# esc_url returns incorrect URL

Tags: php, search

What would be the reason for `<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>` to be sending me to an incorrect website?

I use it in my search bar and when I search a value it sends me to one of my other websites, but I am not sure what I did to make this happen.

Comment: So you are doing something like this? `<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">`. Because the `action` attribute is what defines the website/URL the user is taken to when the search query is submitted.

Comment: That is exactly what  am doing; but it is taking me to a different site of mine, which is odd and when I view the source I see the other site's url.

Comment: Under *Settings > General* in wordpress dashboard, what do you see for "Site Address (URL)"? You might want see if it's set to something else. Otherwise, I am not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Is this a multisite install?

Comment: no it is completely different site with a different url

Comment: Is the actual output in page source correct and matches what you expect?

Comment: the page source shows the wrong url but the search form has - `action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"`

Comment: Also, under the general settings in wordpress it shows the correct url.

Comment: Have you checked `echo get_option('home');` to compare it with `home_url( '/' );`? Any change you're using a plugin or a theme that is messing around with the `home_url` filter ?

Comment: can you elaborate and checking `echo get_option('home');`? If I drop that anywhere it shows the proper url. I don't think any plugin is messing with it, turned them off, and problem exists. I built the theme from scratch, but modified it from the theme I built for another site (which is the site it is forwarding to)....also when i drop `<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>` it gives me the proper url, so where would this messed ups search issue be stemming from??

Comment: I'm checking out the source of the function `get_home_url()` [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0) to see what can influence it's output.

Comment: would it be acceptable to just put my site's url in the `action=""`?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, really stupid thing, basically I always use `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` for my search forms, but for some reason this time I did not and forgot to check the header area where the bar is (could have sworn I checked that first) and the other URL was hardcoded into `action`. When you told me to to try `echo_get_option('home');` it made me recheck the header section, so really your answer helped me solve it...wish I could select it as the proper answer.

Comment: ok great to hear it's solved ;-) Maybe you can answer it and accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being something very easy, but something I overlooked. Since I always use `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` for my search forms, I naturally assume that in my section template for the search area, I was using that, but I was not.

I built the theme custom off of another theme I built for a different website and for some reason in the form's `action=""` I hardcode the url for the first site; that is why I kept getting forwarded there.

I thought I checked the section, but must have overlooked it. After two days or so, I decided to re-check the section, thanks to the suggestions in the comments which made me re-think the problem.

So yeah, really stupid brain fart, but it is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

[`home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) is a Wordpress function that retrieves the home URL for the current site. When called with an optional `$path` argument, it returns the Home URL with the optional `$path` argument appended.

Here's the function definition (from `wp-includes/link-template.php` [L#1959](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1959)):

```
function get_home_url( $blog_id = null, $path = '', $scheme = null ) {
    $orig_scheme = $scheme;

    if ( empty( $blog_id ) || !is_multisite() ) {
        $url = get_option( 'home' );
    } else {
        switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
        $url = get_option( 'home' );
        restore_current_blog();
    }

    if ( ! in_array( $scheme, array( 'http', 'https', 'relative' ) ) ) {
        if ( is_ssl() && ! is_admin() && 'wp-login.php' !== $GLOBALS['pagenow'] )
            $scheme = 'https';
        else
            $scheme = parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME );
    }

    $url = set_url_scheme( $url, $scheme );

    if ( $path && is_string( $path ) )
        $url .= '/' . ltrim( $path, '/' );

    return apply_filters( 'home_url', $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id );
}
```

Basically, there's nothing in this function that would return a random URL out of nowhere.

When situations like this occur, the best thing to do is to `grep` your code for clues.

Run this in a shell in the Wordpress root installation directory:

```
grep -nr "http://randomurl.com"
```

This will list all the occurences of `http://randomurl.com` in your code-base and show the files that they appear in. If there are multiple occurrences, you can use a bit more advanced search (using command line options such as `awk`) to see which one's actually causing troubles.

Note: I know this has already been solved, but this might be useful for future visitors, so I'm posting it as an answer :)